# Data View queries optimization

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

Some simple Queries joining together some **Email Data Views** are timing out and I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding why. They're simple and concrete enough..

Any ideas to tackle this would be most welcome.

```
select
    S.SubscriberKey as ContactKey,
    Sub.EmailAddress,
    S.EventDate as SentDate,
    J.EmailName,
    J.EmailID,
    J.AccountID,
    S.JobID,
    J.DeliveredTime,
    J.Category as EmailCategory,
    J.SuppressTracking as EmailSendSuppressed,
    Sub.Language__pc,
    Sub.Boutique_ID__c,
    B.BounceIsUnique,
    B.EventDate as BounceDate,
    B.BounceCategory,
    B.BounceSubcategory,
    B.BounceType
FROM DV_Send S
INNER JOIN DV_Job J
ON S.JobID = J.JobId
INNER JOIN DV_Subscribers Sub
ON S.SubscriberKey = Sub.SubscriberKey
INNER JOIN DV_Bounces B
ON S.JobID = B.JobID


group by
    S.SubscriberKey,
    Sub.EmailAddress,
    S.EventDate,
    J.EmailName,
    J.EmailID,
    J.AccountID,
    S.JobID,
    Sub.Language__pc,
    Sub.Boutique_ID__c,
    J.DeliveredTime,
    J.Category,
    J.SuppressTracking,
    B.BounceIsUnique,
    B.EventDate,
    B.BounceCategory,
    B.BounceSubcategory,
    B.BounceType
```

[image: DE Fields]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your SQL, it looks like you already have the Data Views going to a data extension and using that for your query instead of the actual data view itself, which is great! (DV_Send vs. _Sent)

So I think really the best way to create this is by breaking it out into multiple queries.

So looks like ContactKey, SentDate, EmailID and JobID are your primary keys - so they need to be grabbed first and included on each following query.

That means first query should be to gather those:

```sql
select
    S.SubscriberKey as ContactKey,
    S.EventDate as SentDate,
    J.EmailID,
    S.JobID,
    J.EmailName,
    J.AccountID,
    J.DeliveredTime,
    J.Category as EmailCategory,
    J.SuppressTracking as EmailSendSuppressed,
FROM DV_Send S
INNER JOIN DV_Job J
ON S.JobID = J.JobId

group by
    S.SubscriberKey,
    S.EventDate,
    J.EmailID,
    S.JobID

/* Action: Update */
/* Target: myDE */
```

Note too that I drastically cut down your 'Group By' statement. This is to ensure the results match add/update to the DE primary keys to reduce errors and increase performance.

Next you can do a single query to gather the info from the Subscribers and Bounces Data or separate those into 2 different ones as well. The primary keys will be grabbed from the target of the original (myDE) and utilized to match the new data to existing records.

Combined:

```sql
select
    S.SubscriberKey as ContactKey,
    S.EventDate as SentDate,
    S.EmailID,
    S.JobID,
    Sub.EmailAddress,
    Sub.Language__pc,
    Sub.Boutique_ID__c,
    B.BounceIsUnique,
    B.EventDate as BounceDate,
    B.BounceCategory,
    B.BounceSubcategory,
    B.BounceType
FROM [myDE] S
INNER JOIN DV_Subscribers Sub
ON S.SubscriberKey = Sub.SubscriberKey
INNER JOIN DV_Bounces B
ON S.JobID = B.JobID

group by
    S.SubscriberKey,
    S.EventDate,
    S.EmailID,
    S.JobID

/* Action: Update */
/* Target: myDE */
```

and then separated for each Data View:

```sql
select
    S.SubscriberKey as ContactKey,
    S.EventDate as SentDate,
    S.EmailID,
    S.JobID,
    Sub.EmailAddress,
    Sub.Language__pc,
    Sub.Boutique_ID__c,
FROM [myDE] S
INNER JOIN DV_Subscribers Sub
ON S.SubscriberKey = Sub.SubscriberKey

group by
    S.SubscriberKey,
    S.EventDate,
    S.EmailID,
    S.JobID

/* Action: Update */
/* Target: myDE */
```

and

```sql
select
    S.SubscriberKey as ContactKey,
    S.EventDate as SentDate,
    S.EmailID,
    S.JobID,
    B.BounceIsUnique,
    B.EventDate as BounceDate,
    B.BounceCategory,
    B.BounceSubcategory,
    B.BounceType
FROM [myDE] S
INNER JOIN DV_Bounces B
ON S.JobID = B.JobID

group by
    S.SubscriberKey,
    S.EventDate,
    S.EmailID,
    S.JobID

/* Action: Update */
/* Target: myDE */
```

Hopefully this will help reduce timeout errors. The issue though is that it will likely be a big increase in overall run time. So be prepared for your runtime to go from like 30mins to around an hour.